# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined at LayoutGapStyleBuilder.buildStyles

Tags: angular, typescript

After upgrading my Angular 8 application to Angular 9, I get the following error in the browser for one template:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined
    at LayoutGapStyleBuilder.buildStyles (flex.js:233)
    at DefaultLayoutGapDirective.addStyles (core.js:492)
    at DefaultLayoutGapDirective.updateWithValue (flex.js:434)
    at MediaMarshaller.updateElement (core.js:3189)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (core.js:3294)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:72)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
    at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at Subject.next (Subject.js:39)
    at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (flex.js:493)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:365)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To catch undefined layout gap values, implement a custom layout gap builder which translates undefined gap values, e.g.:

```
import { Injectable, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  StyleBuilder,
  StyleDefinition,
  LayoutGapParent,
  LayoutGapStyleBuilder,
} from '@angular/flex-layout';

@Injectable()
export class CustomLayoutGapStyleBuilder extends LayoutGapStyleBuilder {
  buildStyles(gapValue: string, parent: LayoutGapParent): StyleDefinition {
      return super.buildStyles(gapValue || '0 px', parent);
  }

  sideEffect(gapValue, _styles, parent) {
      return super.sideEffect(gapValue || '0 px', _styles, parent);
  }

}
```

and make it available to your application in the `@NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  //...
  providers: [
    //...
    { provide: LayoutGapStyleBuilder, useClass: CustomLayoutGapStyleBuilder },
  ],
})
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your fix. This seems like something that should be handled by default by flex layout imo.

Answer (score 20):

I experienced the same problem using:

**Angular 8.0.0**
**Flex-layout 8.0.0-beta.27**

My template had the following top level div:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign.gt-xs="start" fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="20px">
```

Notice that only **fxLayoutGap.gt-xs** is defined.

When emulating a mobile screen (extra small screen) on the Chrome, then trying to hide a div nested under my top level div (using *ngIf) the same error would be thrown. There were no issues for screens greater than extra small (gt-xs)

I think the error occurs when a breakpoint alias (E.g. gt-xs) is defined for fxLayoutGap, but not for the default. Not sure if this is exactly the case for you without seeing your template html.

However, the easiest fix in my case was to add **fxLayoutGap="0px"** as the default value to the div. This resolved the `Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined` error for me.

E.g.

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="0px" fxLayout.gt-xs="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign.gt-xs="start" fxLayoutGap.gt-xs="20px">
```

Comment: Thank You, Glen)

Comment: I had the same error and this solved it, thanks